# Table row value editing is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Table row value editing is not working properly

Click on all edit buttons then try to cancel first one. it will not cancel. 
Can anyone find that mistake?

http://jsfiddle.net/9KEGd/185/

```js
$(function() {
  var currentValue;

  $(".edit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var btn = $(this);
    var td = btn.closest("tr").find(".editable");
    currentValue = td.text();

    if (btn.text() === "edit") {
      td.html("<input type='text' value=" + currentValue + " />");
      btn.html("save");
    } else {
      td.html(td.find("input").val());
      btn.html("edit");
    }
  });

  $(".cancel").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var td = $(this).closest("tr").find(".editable");
    if (currentValue) {
      td.html(currentValue);
      $(this).parent().find(".edit").html("edit");
      currentValue = null;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabledata">
  <thead>
    <th>RecID</th>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>opt</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
        <div class="nestedtable">Tableshowing no need edit</div>
      </a><span class="editable">RecID1</span></td>
    <td>Val1.1</td>
    <td><button class="edit">edit</button><button class="cancel">cancel</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
        <div class="nestedtable">Tableshowings no need edit</div>
      </a><span class="editable">RecID2</span></td>
    <td>Val2.1</td>
    <td><button class="edit">edit</button><button class="cancel">cancel</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
        <div class="nestedtable">Tableshowing no need edit</div>
      </a><span class="editable">RecID3</span></td>
    <td>Val3.1</td>
    <td><button class="edit">edit</button><button class="cancel">cancel</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @mplungjan: it's not working fine. Check `jsfiddle` click on all edit buttons then try to cancel first one. it will not cancel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your variable `currentValue`. When at once editing one field it works fine but when You try to do editing for more after closing first one `currentValue` is assigned to null and it blocks posibility to close rest(if statement in close function). Another problem is that in this way You will lost your saved text for input when start editing multiple fields at once. Possible solution is to save text in data attribute for each field.

```js
$(function () {
  
    $(".edit").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var btn = $(this);
        var td = btn.closest("tr").find(".editable");
        
        var currentValue = td.text();

        //Save current text in td data attribute
        $(td).data("current-value", currentValue);
        
        if(btn.text() === "edit")
        {
         td.html("<input type='text' value="+currentValue+" />");
            btn.html("save");
        }
        else
        {
         td.html(td.find("input").val());
            btn.html("edit");
        }

    });
    
     $(".cancel").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();  
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var td = $(this).closest("tr").find(".editable");
        
        //Read data attribute to get saved text
        var currentValue = $(td).data("current-value");
        if(currentValue != "")
        {
         td.html(currentValue);
            $(this).parent().find(".edit").html("edit");

            //Set attribute to empty string
            $(td).data("current-value", "");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabledata">
    <thead>
        <th>RecID</th>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>opt</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
    <td><a><div class="nestedtable">Tableshowing no need edit</div></a><span class="editable">RecID1</span></td>
        <td>Val1.1</td>
        <td><button class="edit">edit</button><button class="cancel">cancel</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><a><div class="nestedtable">Tableshowings no need edit</div></a><span class="editable">RecID2</span></td>
        <td>Val2.1</td>
        <td><button class="edit">edit</button><button class="cancel">cancel</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a><div class="nestedtable">Tableshowing no need edit</div></a><span class="editable">RecID3</span></td>
        <td>Val3.1</td>
        <td><button class="edit">edit</button><button class="cancel">cancel</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: click all the edit button then click one by one cancel button. see first click only working after that cancel button not working for all:http://jsfiddle.net/9KEGd/186/

Comment: I already did it in answer.  It's based on your code, only js changed. If You want to get some info about data attributes take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `currentValue` gets last value you clicked on `edit` and when you `cancel` one, it gets the last input value and turn it to `null` so the other `cancel` buttons don't work.

You can just work with id's so you can store all values separately:

```js
$(function() {
  var currentValue = {};

  $(".edit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var btn = $(this);
    var td = btn.closest("tr").find(".editable");
    currentValue[td.attr("id")] = td.text();

    if (btn.text() === "edit") {
      td.html("<input id='"+td.attr("id")+"' type='text' value=" + currentValue[td.attr("id")] + " />");
      btn.html("save");
    } else {
      td.html(td.find("input").val());
      btn.html("edit");
    }
  });

  $(".cancel").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var td = $(this).closest("tr").find(".editable");
    if (currentValue[td.attr("id")]) {
      td.html(currentValue[td.attr("id")]);
      $(this).parent().find(".edit").html("edit");
      currentValue[td.attr("id")] = null;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabledata">
  <thead>
    <th>RecID</th>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>opt</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
        <div class="nestedtable">Tableshowing no need edit</div>
      </a><span id="1" class="editable">RecID1</span></td>
    <td>Val1.1</td>
    <td>
      <button class="edit">edit</button>
      <button class="cancel">cancel</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
        <div class="nestedtable">Tableshowings no need edit</div>
      </a><span id="2" class="editable">RecID2</span></td>
    <td>Val2.1</td>
    <td>
      <button class="edit">edit</button>
      <button class="cancel">cancel</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
        <div class="nestedtable">Tableshowing no need edit</div>
      </a><span id="3" class="editable">RecID3</span></td>
    <td>Val3.1</td>
    <td>
      <button class="edit">edit</button>
      <button class="cancel">cancel</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: do not use id bcos row added by dinamicaly

Comment: Click all the edit button then click one by one cancel button. see cancel button first click only working after that cancel buttons not working for all.check:http://jsfiddle.net/9KEGd/186/

Comment: You can add id dinamically by (for example) having a counter when you create them, **by the way**, you are using _ChandrakantThakkar_ solution, and the main problem is _currentValue_ because is still being overriden by the last input value and when you click on a _cancel_ button setted to null. You must differentiate the input values or let the user edit only one input at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Please put below code in your cancel button

```
$(".cancel").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();  
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var td = $(this).closest("tr").find(".editable");

    if(currentValue && $(this).closest("tr").find("input").length==1)
    {
        td.html(currentValue);
      $(this).parent().find(".edit").html("edit");
      currentValue = null;
    }
});
```

Now, you can only cancel on which row you have pressed edit.
while in edit mode there is no any use of cancel button in all others row so I have disabled them.

Comment: can you specify what is issue now?because I have checked it's working as per requirement but when you press any cancel button it's not work .You need to cancel only such row in that you have pressed edit.

Comment: click all the edit button then click one by one cancel button. see first click  only working after that cancel button not working for all

Comment: I think you got answer that is correct.Please try that when click on edit then only cancel and save button activated otherwise there is only edit button should be there.Thanks